# Flutter bloc how to make the block update when the page is closed

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am using bloc in my application which is loading sales data, I have a button to view sales details in which I use `Navigator.push`. I need to update my `WarehouseSalesBloc` state when I leave the product details page.

Here is code example:

```
// WarehouseSalesPage

  final _detailsBloc = SalesDetailsBloc();
  String printUrl = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _detailsBloc.add(LoadSalesDetails(id: widget.id));
  }


          BlocProvider<WarehouseSalesBloc>(
              create: (context) => WarehouseSalesBloc(),
              child: BlocBuilder<WarehouseSalesBloc, WarehouseSalesState>(
                bloc: _salesBloc,
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state is WarehouseSalesLoading) {
                    return const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  } else if (state is WarehouseSalesLoaded) {
                    return ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => 
 // i need to update my warehouse sales page after closing WareHouseSalesDetails
                                          WareHouseSalesDetails(
                                invoiceId: sales.invoiceId,
                                id: sales.id,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Открыть',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                          ),
                        ));
                  } else if (state is WarehouseSalesLoadingFailure) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text(state.exception.toString()),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return const Center(
                      child: Text('Something went wrong'),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ))
```

I tried adding after `Navigator.push`     .then(value) =>
but that doesn't help either
Also if I wrap my `WareHouseSalesDetails` page in `WillPopScope` and add it to onWillPop
`onWillPop: () async { Provider.of<WarehouseSalesBloc>(context).add(LoadSalesDetails()); return true; },`
this won't work either.

How can i update the state of my bloc after closing the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are defining your bloc instanse in the same calss, so bu default it will be killed immediatly after the object is disposed.

you should initiate it outside the class and use BlocProvider.value().

i suggest get_it package to register your instanse of bloc
here is the link: [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it)

Comment: Could you give an example based on my code how should I do this?

Comment: 1. in your main(), add the initialization of the package i mentioned previously, 
`init()` 

2.inside `init()` , register your bloc as shown in the docs.

3.use it wherever you want